# Set backgroundImage to Style without Relative Path in Jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

My code below doesn't work, not sure why I can't just use `../images/login-bg.png` but have to import it.

```
import loginBg from '../images/login-bg.png';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;
    return (
      <div style={{backgroundImage: url(loginBg)}}>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While providing `background image` with inline styles, provide within quotes like

```
import loginBg from '../images/login-bg.png';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;
    return (
      <div style={{backgroundImage: "url(" + loginBg + ")"}}></div>
    )
  }
}
```

or make use of template literals like

```
<div style={{backgroundImage: `url(${loginBg})`}}>
```